# Failing ssh login

Tags: ssh, vmware

I currently have Ubuntu 16.0.4 running on VMWare Fusion 10. 
I am trying to ssh into the box and have already installed openssh server on the box. However, the problem is that I am not able to ssh into the box from my local machine.

I usually run

```
ssh aneakell@192.168.2.134
```

I can successfully ping google.com from the box and download various packages. So, I don't think it is a network issue.

I typed in ifconfig -a and took the ip address from ens33 which was 192.168.2.134. However, the connection is unable to be made.
Can someone give me suggestions as to why?

[Image of output of ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bih4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the machine your trying to ssh from is in the same subnet. Try changing the adapter type in the VM settings to Bridged or Host-only.

Comment: What do you mean by same subnet? I tried changing the adapter type but no change.

Comment: See in ifconfig, the IP is 192.168.2.X and your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 otherwise known as a /24 network. This means the machine you are trying to ping from must also have an IP of 192.168.2.x

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was go to Security and Preferences and turn off the firewall. It should work. After the connection is made, you can turn the firewall back on.